# Cab Replace ALL FILES vs Replace one file

Tags: compact-framework, cab

when the user clicks on cab file to update the app, I would like them to have the option to NOT replace all the files each time. Even though there are 2 choice in the dialogue that comes up, YES and YES TO ALL will replace ALL the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in wceload has no provision to do that.  You could always write your own replacement for wceload that does have a custom UI using something like the [CAB installer SDK](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/CABInstallerSDK/tabid/272/Default.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I was looking for a quick fix. I'm working on the self-updating feature now and won't need anyone to manually update the app. The config file is currently in the .cab and won't be in the future. It's just strange that there 2 options: replace one file and replace all, but both do the same.

Comment: Yeah, wceload (and cabwiz for that matter) sucks pretty badly.